# I have this array and I have to make pattern like this

Tags: arrays, pattern-matching

array = [2, 4, 3, 9, 6, 5];

and we have to print like this

```
      *
      *
      *
      * * 
      * * *
  *   * * *
  * * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * * *
```

I have tried the normal nested for loop 1st loop for row, 2nd for spaces, and third for printing star.

Comment: What language? How the input numbers correlate with `*`?

Comment: Question is not uploaded properly

Comment: Suraj please add more details on how you want this problem to be solved, in which language, or maybe in pseudo code? This will help others to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: basically I have an array [2, 4, 3, 9, 6, 5] and I want to print a pattern, each array element like 2 has to print in col wise like I have mentioned in pattern and I want this in c++

Answer (score 0):

In C# it could look like:

```cs
var height = array.Max();
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",
        array.Select(x => x >= height - i ? "*" : " ")));
}
```